# PDFBox- extract section from flattened PDF with yellow background

Tags: java, automation, pdfbox

As part of the api response I am getting returned certain pdf documents which are flattened and read only.

I need to validate if certain sections in the pdf which contain signature are highlighted in yellow or not. Problem I am facing is I tried several ways to get the yellow region extracted for validation but it doesn't work.

I tried using PDAnnotation but it doesn't work. it doesn't return any annotation. Also tried PDFTextStripper for checking using pattern for yellow color in extracted text, doesn't work. Tried using Tesseract class but it requires additional language data files which I may not be able to use.

Comment: If you know the position, then render the page and find out the color.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for the suggestion.I tried rendering the pdf page to an image and then got a subimage from that by passing coordinates of the highlighted region. Then using getRGB function was able to validate the color of the highlighted region.